# Can tf.saved_model.simple_save be used to create a SavedModel for C++?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I want to save a model for inference from C++ and I am looking into `SavedModel`s as [suggested by the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#save_and_restore_models).

Now [`tf.saved_model.simple_save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save) seems to be a convenience function to easily create a `SavedModel`: from within a `Session`, provide the inputs, outputs and an export dir:

```
simple_save(session,
            export_dir,
            inputs={"x": x, "y": y},
            outputs={"z": z})
```

When looking at this API, the function looks rather broad in application; however the documentation warns us that

> The `SavedModel` will load in TensorFlow Serving and supports the Predict API. To use the Classify, Regress, or MultiInference APIs, please use either `tf.Estimator` or the lower level `SavedModel` APIs.

I am not familiar with Tensorflow serving, but it seems that these distinctions between Predict, Classify aso. relates to Tensorflow serving.

Actually the documentaiton on `tf.saved_model.simple_save` says that it is a

> Convenience function to build a SavedModel **suitable for serving**.

(emphasis mine).

So `tf.saved_model.simple_save` can create `SavedModel`s for serving, but my question is,

- can `tf.saved_model.simple_save` also be used to create a `SavedModel` for inference in C++,
- if so, what are the limitation in terms of models that can be created by this function? (Given the fact that for serving, it apparently does have some restrictions.)